# Is it appropriate to consider the interactions between blocking and fixed factors

Tags: anova, interaction, random-effects-model, blocking

If you have an experiment with multiple treatments (lets say 4 fixed factors with varying levels each) and you use a randomized complete block design, is it appropriate to consider the interactions between the block (random factor) and your fixed factors?

*I ask because I use jmp and the modeling option allows you to add each factor and interaction individually*

Answer (score 2):

If you want account for the possibility that treatment effects differ between blocks, you should not specify this as a fixed interaction, but as a random slope. See http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/videos/random-slopes.html

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but I'm not sure I understand your answer @FlorianHartig. The video on that page did not work and I am not great with the actual statistical modelling using maths. 

Do you mean that the interactions in the model between fixed factors (treatments) should remain fixed, but if I consider interactions between fixed factors and random factors (blocks), they should also be made to be random factors? If so, thanks, that makes sense. If not, I'm afraid I am a bit lost, because I'm not used to thinking in terms of slopes/intercepts :(

Comment: "but if I consider interactions between fixed factors and random factors (blocks), they should also be made to be random factors?" -> exactly, this is called a random slope. Given your question, I would advice to search help from a statistician to do this.